# Algorithmically determining attributes of an object instance

Tags: design

I am developing a game idea that has a large collection of objects/widgets (let's say 5 billion objects). They each have specific attributes as follows:

- style (10 styles)
- pattern  (4 patterns)
- color (10 colors)
- type (15 types)
- etc.
- etc.
- etc.

(The number of attribute categories has not currently been determined).

An example: Object #1 bight have:

- Style: 1
- Pattern: 3
- Color: 4
- Type: 7

Each object is given an id number such as 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, ... 5,000,000,000.

**My question:**

How do I distribute these attributes evenly to allow for:

1. The greatest variation of objects
2. Upon being given a particular object number: (ex. 527331) how to determine what it's attributes would be?
3. The greatest spread. So objects with the exact same characteristics are not next to each other. (This is a preferred requirement, but is optional)

**A failed idea:**

I thought about using the modulo operator such as:

527331 / 10 to determine the style

But, since there are 10 styles and 10 colors, then that would mean that all objects with style 1 would also have color 1. So, we'd never see objects of style 1 with color 2, etc.

Comment: Introduce a concept that is the grouping of all properties and has a unique identification. Group with id 1 is style 1, pattern 1, color 1, etc. Then you could use your module idea based on the group count.

Comment: @RikD Ultimately, there may be quite a number of attributes with quite a number of variations that we may end up with several thousand groups.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest and easiest approach is probably to just randomize each attribute. If you have lots of attributes this should ensure good variation and distribution. If you want to use the ID number to determine the attributes you could use it as the seed for a random number generator before generating the attributes.

If you need to guarantee uniqueness you need to do some more work. Each possible set of attributes can be described as a number, and you need to map your IDs to this set of attribute ids. If you have N possible combination of attributes you could generate a list of 0..N numbers and shuffle this list. So when you use your id as an index you will have an random but unique number in the 0..N range. You can then split this number number into attributes by combining division and modulus, i.e.

```
style = n % 10 
n = n / 10 
pattern  = n % 4
n = n / 4
etc....
```

There is may be some clever mathematical transform that lets you do something equivalent without actually creating a list and shuffling it, but that is beyond me.

Answer (score 0):

> 2. Upon being given a particular object number: (ex. 527331) how to determine what it's attributes would be?

If you want to do this without actually loading the object into memory, then you need to encode the attribute values into the ID in some way.

The easiest way is very close to what you tried with the modulo operator: The last digit represents the style, then going left you have the pattern, color, 2 digits for type, etc.

If you are comfortable working with bit operations, you can also choose to do 4 bits style, 2 bits pattern, 4 bits color, 4 bits type, etc.

The most significant bits/digits (the left-most ones), you can use for a kind of sequence number for objects that otherwise have the same properties.